# How to fetch configmap from kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have one spring boot microservice running on docker container, below is the Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8-jre
MAINTAINER <>
WORKDIR deploy/
#COPY config/* /deploy/config/
COPY ./ms.console.jar /deploy/
CMD chmod +R 777 ./ms.console.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","/deploy/ms.console.jar","console"]
EXPOSE 8384
```

here my configuration stores in external folder, i.e `/config/console-server.yml` and when I started the application, internally it will load the config (spring boot functionality).

Now I want to separate this configuration using configmap, for that I simply created one configmap and storing all the configuration details.

> kubectl create configmap console-configmap
>   --from-file=./config/console-server.yml
>
> kubectl describe configmap console-configmap

below are the description details:

```
Name:         console-configmap
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
console-server.yml:
----
server:
  http:
    port: 8385
  compression:
    enabled: true
    mime-types: application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/javascript
    min-response-size: 2048

---
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    prefix: classpath:/static
  application:
    name: console-service
  profiles:
     active: native
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 30MB
      max-request-size: 30MB
---
host:
  gateway: http://apigateway:4000
  webhook: http://localhost:9000
```

my deployment yml is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.8.0 use apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: consoleservice1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: consoleservice
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 3 pods matching the template
  template: # create pods using pod definition in this template
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: consoleservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: consoleservice
        image: ms-console
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8384
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: console-configmap
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcresd
```

My doubt is, I commented config folder in the Dockerfile, so while running pods, it's throwing exception because of no configuration, how I will inject this console-configmap to my deployment, what I tried already shared, but getting same issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, how are you consuming the .yml file in your application? If you consume your yml file contents as environment variables, your config should just work fine. But I suspect that you want to consume the contents from the config file inside the container. If that is the case you have to create a volume out of the configmap as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.8.0 use apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: consoleservice1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: consoleservice
  replicas: 1 # tells deployment to run 3 pods matching the template
  template: # create pods using pod definition in this template
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: consoleservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: consoleservice
        image: ms-console
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8384
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /app/config
            name: config
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: console-configmap
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcresd
```

The file will be available in the path `/app/config/console-server.yml`. You have to modify it as per your needs.

Comment: Hi Malathi ,thank you ,yes I am not using env variable ,so I have to inject configuration like this ,though my workdir is deploy ,so mountpath will be /deploy/config and could you please help me on config-map ,I am using below command for creating console-configmap .kubectl create configmap console-configmap --from-file=./config/console-server.yml ,this path is my local path ,how it will change dynamically to my container image ,?

Comment: There are no paths defined once you create a configmap. When you define a volumeMount in deployment yaml, you specify the path. In the above example, I specified the volume to be mounted on `/app/config`. So the file is available in the path `/app/config/console-server.yml`.In the above answer, if you change the mountPath to /deploy, the file gets available on /deploy/console-server.yml

Comment: the file path what we talking is it my local file path or inside my container path ?sorry I am totaly new to this ,little confused .

Comment: It is container path. Kubernetes deployment collects info to run the containers

Comment: Hi ,Now I am not copied my config directory while creating  container instance (above dockerfile) ,as we are going to inject it runtime using configmap ,but getting error because of no configuration  :(

Comment: able to resolve ,thanks a lot for listening my issues and giving answer .

Answer (score 1):

do you need to load key:value pairs from the config file as environment variables then below spec would work

```
envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: console-configmap
```

if you need the config as a file inside pod then mount the configmap as volume. following link would be helpful
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/configuration/configure-redis-using-configmap/

Comment: Hi ,could you please provide more clarity on this ,means you are saying I have to keep the config with images and using configmap I can modified the configuration at runtime ,is it correct ?

Comment: Yes. Using configMap you can decouple the application configuration from application image